# redefinition of static function in case of inheritance

Tags: c++, scope, static-functions

```
class base
{
public:
  static void func()
  {
    cout<<"in base class\n";
  }
};

class derived: public base
{
public:
  void func()
  {
    cout<<"In derived class\n";
  }
};

main() {
  derived d;
  d.func();
}
```

If I make a function static in base class and create a function in derived class with the same name,why does that function get redefined even when it is static??

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get redefined, if it did you would have a compilation error due to the one definition rule. You have 2 functions here, one a member, and one static. `d.func()` is the member function ( as the `.` suggests ). The other function is `base::func()`, which is the static function ( as `::` suggests ).

Answer (score 1):

It does not get redefined, or you would violate the one-definition-rule.

What you see is "scope":
If a name is defined in an inner scope, it shadows (hides) all definitions of the same name in an outer scope.

You can still refer to the function in the outer scope (base class) with an explicit qualification:

```
base::func
```

In order to add those from the outer scope to the overload set, use a `using`-declaration:

```
using base::func;
```

If you do so, `base::func` will be called when using `derived::func()` and `derived::func` will be called when using `derivedobject.func()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing "shadowing". The same thing is possible with member functions:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    void func() { std::cout << "in base\n"; }
};

struct D : public B {
    void func() { std::cout << "in derived\n"; }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.func();
}
```

http://ideone.com/kjt2Oa

This - as others have suggested - is called "shadowing", one definition hides the other.

The important thing to remember here is that static function calling is resolved at compile time. So the following would have the behavior you had anticipated, but it is technically the wrong behavior because it prevents you from calling the top-most 'func' when using a base class pointer:

```
void callFunc(base* b) {
    b->func();
}

int main() {
    derived d;
    callFunc(&b);
}
```

because at the call site, `b->` points to `base` and would call `base::func` instead of `derived::func`. At compile time, all the compiler knows is that 'b' is `base`.

Most people expect and want the dynamic behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Animal {
    const char* say() { return "???"; }
};

struct Fox : public Animal {
    const char* say() { return "A ring ding ding"; }
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
    const char* say() { return "Meow"; }
};

void whatDoesItSay(const char* name, Animal* animal) {
    std::cout << "The " << name << " says " << animal->say() << ".\n";
}

int main() {
    Cat cat;
    Fox fox;
    whatDoesItSay("cat", &cat);
    whatDoesItSay("fox", &fox);
}
```

http://ideone.com/9wIzq7

This doesn't have the desired behavior:

Instead we need to use the keyword 'virtual' in the base class to indicate that we want fully polymorphic behavior, and we can use the new C++11 keyword 'override' to ensure we're doing it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Animal {
    virtual const char* say() { return "???"; }
};

struct Fox : public Animal {
    const char* say() override { return "A ring ding ding"; }
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
    const char* say() override { return "Meow"; }
};

void whatDoesItSay(const char* name, Animal* animal) {
    std::cout << "The " << name << " says " << animal->say() << ".\n";
}

int main() {
    Cat cat;
    Fox fox;
    whatDoesItSay("cat", &cat);
    whatDoesItSay("fox", &fox);
}
```

http://ideone.com/uOtYMv